# Using collections.Counter on large pickle data

Tags: python

I have a pickle file with over a million words in it. The pickle file can be downloaded from [here](http://turkish-nlp.com/datanlp/words.pkl).

I want to use `Counter` on these words to sort them. Here's my code:

```
with open('data/words.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = list(pickle.load(f))

print(Counter(data).most_common(3))
```

The printed result changes every time, but it's usually like this:

```
[('', 1), ('fraksiyonal', 1), ('editado', 1)]
```

So, it seems to be not counting the words and every word's occurrence is 1. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
As an example of how data list looks:

```
print(data[0:10])
```

Result:

```
['', 'hillview', 'dipnota', 'дол', 'censusi', 'quathie', 'kalacağının', 'stralauerstrasse', 'sbaglio', 'keny']
```

Comment: Does the problem occur with smaller amounts of data? What does your data look like (I don't want to download a 1M file in order to see it)?

Comment: What is the actual structure of the data, if you didn't apply `list()` to it?  It may be doing something special with repeated words already, such that your `Counter` never sees more than one of any particular word.  The alternative is that your file contains nothing but distinct words.

Comment: Are you sure that the words are repeated more than one time?

Comment: @jasonharper This pickle was created by parsing and filtering a Turkish Wikipedia dump, which doesn't only have distinct words. It doesn't really do anything with the words, they're in a similar state to the printed list (I edited it in), I changed it to list because pickle load data is a set object, which is not subscriptable and a few other things, and I need it to be.

Comment: regarding *"The printed result changes every time"*, you should be able to get a consistent result with `sorted(Counter(data))[:3]`. Speaking of, that means you're using Python 3.6 or lower, right?

Comment: @wjandrea Oh, I'm an idiot. Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: @Elif Happens to all of us :) welcome. (I swapped out my comment for an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your data. In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412836/using-collections-counter-on-large-pickle-data#comment110383349_62412836) you said,

> I changed it to list because pickle load data is a set object

Sets can't contain duplicates, hence why the counts are always 1.

---

*due credit to [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) for posting [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412836/using-collections-counter-on-large-pickle-data/62413628#comment110382718_62412836) that figured it out*